# Ajax pagination with primefaces dataList and URL parameter

Tags: java, jsf, pagination, primefaces

I'm trying out PrimeFaces combined with JSF and Xhtml templates. I have one page that displays  a DataList with pagination enabled. The URL for the profile page is profilePage.xhtml?userId=1 but the DataList component calls to profilePage.xhtml when asking for the next 'page'.

Is there any way to make the PrimeFaces components keep the URL params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this by annotating ajax pages with @ViewState and reading the query param with viewparams.